# php preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$flr = preg_replace("/\\\'/","%27",$flr);
```

If url has this symbol: **'** it got replaced by %27 and url should become http://localhost/%27
But this doesn't work. For example:

`$flr = preg_replace("/\\\"/","%22",$flr);`

url replacment works and i get http://localhost/%22

Then why first example doesn't work ?

To test i'm using:

```
function isValidFLR(&$flr) {
  $flr = preg_replace("/\\\'/","%27",$flr);
  $flr = preg_replace("/\\\"/","%22",$flr);
  echo $flr;
  die();
}
```

Comment: why dont u try [rawurlencode](http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$flr = preg_replace("/'/","%27",$flr);
```

will work.

But, as others have said, one of the PHP functions which does this could be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is what you asking for simply [`urlencode()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) ?

If you just want to replace a couple of certain characters, you should perhaps try using `str_replace()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're having problems with PHP's string escaping of quotes, getting mixed in with regex's escaping. You could end up with a very messy sequence of backslashes!

The most direct solution for your problem is simply to use single quotes on your regex string when you're searching for double-quotes:

```
$flr = preg_replace('/\\\"/',"%22",$flr);
```

However, in your case, an even simpler solution is going begging: Why do you need to use regex at all in this case? A simple `str_replace()` would do this job just as well, and would avoid all those hair-raising slashes.

Answer (score 0):

What about to test with following :

```
$flr = preg_replace("/\\\"/","%27",$flr);
```

(replace **'** to **"**)